# How to modify an expression to pass it to a method

Tags: c#-4.0, expression

The problem is:

```
public GetAll(Expression<Func<CampModel, bool>> whereCondition)
{
   // and it should call another GetAllCampsFromRepo method that gets Camps from a repository
}

public IList<Camp> GetAllCampsFromRepo(Expression<Func<Camp, bool>> whereCondition)
{
     return // Blah blah the list of Camps
}
```

So the question is how correctly call the second method from the body of the first method, mapping properties of different types - CampModel object to Camp object (they are similar but different)

How can I transform `whereCondition`so I could pass it to the `GetAllCampsFromRepo`? Because I can't pass it as is:

```
GetAllCampsFromRepo(whereCondition)
```

Can I use something like System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor and modify the original expression? How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a related question that might help.
[How do I translate an expression tree of one type to a different expression type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698553/how-do-i-translate-an-expression-tree-of-one-type-to-a-different-expression-type/6698584#6698584)