# How do I translate an expression tree of one type to a different expression type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

If I have two nearly identical classes `Animal` and `AnimalViewModel` and an expression tree related to the viewmodel, how can I translate it to `Animal`?

```
public class Animal
{
   public string Species { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Sound { get; set; }
}
public class AnimalViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public string Species { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Sound { get; set; }
}
```

How can I translate an `Expression<Func<AnimalViewModel,bool>>` to `Expression<Func<Animal,bool>>`?

```
public static Expression<Func<Animal,bool>> Translate (Expression<Func<AnimalViewModel,bool>> expression)
{
  // What goes here?  I assume I have to traverse the tree somehow.
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a visitor that does the job.

- it makes a copy of the parameter (since we'll need to create a new parameter and substitute all references of the old parameter for the new one)
- it walks the `.Body` of the tree, substituting the parameter, and switching any member-access against the *old* type to a like-named member on the *new* type
- it re-assembles a lambda using the parameter we invented earler

Code:

```
class TypeChangeVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Type from, to;
    private readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> substitutions;
    public TypeChangeVisitor(Type from, Type to, Dictionary<Expression, Expression> substitutions)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.substitutions = substitutions;
    }
    public override Expression  Visit(Expression node)
    { // general substitutions (for example, parameter swaps)
        Expression found;
        if(substitutions != null && substitutions.TryGetValue(node, out found))
        {
            return found;
        }
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    { // if we see x.Name on the old type, substitute for new type
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == from)
        {
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(node.Expression),
                to.GetMember(node.Member.Name, node.Member.MemberType,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Single());
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<AnimalViewModel, bool>> predicate = x => x.Name == "abc";
        var switched = Translate<AnimalViewModel, Animal>(predicate);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<TTo, bool>> Translate<TFrom, TTo>(Expression<Func<TFrom, bool>> expression)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TTo), expression.Parameters[0].Name);
        var subst = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { expression.Parameters[0], param } };
        var visitor = new TypeChangeVisitor(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo), subst);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TTo, bool>>(visitor.Visit(expression.Body), param);
    }
}
```

Note that if you have `x.Something.Name` you might need to be a bit more careful, but this should get you a reasonable way.

Comment: Why it doesn't work if you derive AnimalViewModel from an abstract class that has a public property? Although if you put the very same property to the AnimalViewModel and not into the abstract class, it will work

Comment: @Agzam replace DeclaringType with ReflectedType in that case

Comment: check for yourself - if you have Int Id in Animal and also AnimalViewModel derived from BaseViewModel which holds Id. And if you try to use Id in predicate wouldn't work. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for something like this?