# How to convert the property selector in Expression<Func<MyClass, int>>?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have the following expression type:

`Expression<Func<MyClass, int>>`

How can I convert it to a...

`Expression<Func<MyClass, object>>`

...and then back to a...

`Expression<Func<MyClass, int>>`

Comment: Here is a related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698553/how-do-i-translate-an-expression-tree-of-one-type-to-a-different-expression-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you could just use `Expression.Convert`:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, int>> original = ...;

var conversion = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, object>>(
        Expression.Convert(original.Body, typeof(object)),
        original.Parameters);

var conversionBack = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, int>>(
        Expression.Convert(conversion.Body, typeof(int)),
        original.Parameters);
```

EDIT: Okay, it *looks* like it works:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<string, int>> original = x => x.Length;
        var conversion = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, object>(
              Expression.Convert(original.Body, typeof(object)),
              original.Parameters);

        var conversionBack = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, int>>(
              Expression.Convert(conversion.Body, typeof(int)),
              original.Parameters);

        Console.WriteLine(conversion); // x => Convert(x.Length)
        Console.WriteLine(conversionBack); // x => Convert(Convert(x.Length))

        Console.WriteLine(conversion.Compile()("Hello")); // 5
        Console.WriteLine(conversionBack.Compile()("Hello")); // 5
    }
}
```