# How to use create from DTO and Map DTO for Expression<Func<TDomainDto, bool>> predicat

Tags: c#, oop

I use from CreateFormDto Method and MapDto Method for convert DTO to Entity and also Entity to DTO. Now I can not convert these, for example:

```
public Paginated<TDomainDto> SearchPage(Expression<Func<TDomainDto, bool>> predicate, int page, int size)
{
    return BaseService.SearchPage(predicate: predicate, page: page, size: size);
}
```

I get error in this line `(predicate: predicate,` and this error is `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TDomainDto, bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TDomain, bool>>'`

Comment: is TDomainDto inherited from TDomain? Try to add it into Generic type constraint

Comment: @ASpirin No, I have a TDomainDto and i want convert to TDomain.  i do not Know how to resolve it  because it is a Expression

Comment: Sounds like you have to translate `Expression<Func<TDomainDto, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>>` function `map` wouldn't help

Comment: Don't want to copy content of the answer, so check the answer to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698553/how-do-i-translate-an-expression-tree-of-one-type-to-a-different-expression-type